# Cypress with laradock

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cypress, laradock

I've setup a laravel project with laradock. Project can be accessed from url `http://blog.localhost`

I have written a sample test file to visit the application url but I get the following error.

[image]

How do I setup cypress to visit my project URL ?

Comment: Are you able to access `http://blog.localhost` on a external web browser on your machine ?

Comment: Yes, I'm able access it from my other regular browser but not from cypress test browsers.

Comment: How about you add the port number as well, where the application is running and try again `http://blog.localhost:8080`. 8080 is just an example, add the relevant port number.